# Execute javascript when another function exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing two scripts in an web environment where I don't have control over the order in which they are loaded.  Let's say the two scripts are called `MyUtil` and `DoSomething`.

`MyUtil` contains utilities that I will bind to the `window` object using `window.myUtil = myUtil`.  I'm then going to call methods of `myUtil` from within `DoSomething`.

If `MyUtil` is loaded first, everything will work. If it's loaded second, `window.myUtil` will be `undefined`.

How can I modify the code in `DoSomething` (and/or MyUtil) to wait until `window.myUtil` exists before `DoSomething` executes its code?

*NB: I'm using jQuery 1.2.3.*

Comment: Do you have access to the code that dynamically loads `MyUtil`?  If so, you can use `jQuery.getScript()` to load it and then call `DoSomething` in the success callback.

Comment: @Rob I *could* go that route, but in the environment I'm in, I think that would introduce more maintenance in the long term on my part.

Answer (score 7):

`jQuery.Deferred` objects provide a very elegant way to do this (I know you're not using jQuery 1.5: I'm just giving you a reason to upgrade `;-)`:

Assuming we have two scripts co-operating like the following:

```
// defines utilities    
var util = util || { loaded: $.Deferred() };
(function(){
    $.extend(util, {
        msg: "Hello!"
    });
    util.loaded.resolve();
})();
```

... and:

```
// uses them
var util = util || { loaded: $.Deferred() };
util.loaded.then(function(){
    alert(util.msg);
});
```

... the alert will always fire after the first script has had a chance to define it's utilities no matter the order they load in. This has advantages over the `setTimeout` and event based approaches in that it's easier to have multiple dependencies (using `$.when`), doesn't use polling, and you don't have to worry about handling the order-of-loading explicitly.

The only thing that's kind of gross is that all of the modules have to include:

```
var util = util || { loaded: $.Deferred() };
```

... and `$.extend()` it to make sure that they use the same deferred.

Comment: +1 This is excellent. I'm using RSVP and just plugged a deferred into my module without having to use $.extend.

Comment: @Aaron Could you please explain the advantage of using a self-invoking function and `$.extend()` vs `util.msg = "Hello!"; util.loaded.resolve();`

Answer (score 4):

### Wait Until myUtil is Available

You could set a timer using `window.setInterval()` to wait until `window.myUtil` has been set before attempting to use it.

### Example

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/CtJ8A/1/

Simulating a situation where `window.myUtil` is added *after* the script that requires it has been loaded:

```
window.setTimeout((function(){
    window.myUtil = { 
        utility: function(){ alert('utility has great utility!'); }   
    };
}), 5000);
```

Elsewhere in your page:

```
// Declaration of function that requires window.myUtil
var doSomething = function() {
     window.myUtil.utility();   
}

/* 
 * Timer that checks for myUtil every 100 milliseconds 
 * When myUtil does exist, the timer is cleared, and doSomething() is called.
 *
 * Alternatively, one could put this timer inside doSomething().
 */
var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        if (window.myUtil != undefined) {
            window.clearInterval(timer);
            doSomething();
        }
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a trigger in MyUtil that I check for in DoSomething. This worked perfectly.

At the end of MyUtil, I added:

```
$(document).trigger('myUtilLoaded');
```

At the end of DoSomething, I added:

```
if (!(window.myUtil))
{
  $(document).bind('myUtilLoaded', function(e) {
    doSomething();
  });
}
else
{
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: what if myutil gets loaded first, myUtilLoaded will trigger but nothing will be bound to it

Comment: @james good point. Updated to check for the existence of `myUtil` first.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

```
$('body').load(function() {
    window.myUtil.utility();        
});
```

Comment: He doesn't know when 'myUtil' will be added.

Comment: Yeah, `$(document).ready()` was the first thing I tried and that didn't work.

Comment: I figured he just wasn't sure which order the script files would be included in the original HTML.  So waiting for the load event should guarantee that all the script files have been downloaded.  If the script files are loaded dynamically this wouldn't work.

Comment: I believe the script files are loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
 function function1(callback){
        var params={
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ajax/doSomethingSlow.php",
            data: "",
            success: function(msg){
                callback(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                callback('');
            }
        };
        var result=$.ajax(params).responseText;
    }




function1(function(){
   //call function2 here:
   function2();
});
```

Comment: While that might work from a technical perspective, I really don't want to use artificial timing games to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic loading to load the javascript, but if you also arent in control of where the script located then i suppose this could be an issue as well.

Anyhow in do something you would basiically pull down the script via ajax or use a `document.write` to insert a new script tag:

```
function doSomething(){
  if(!window.myUtil){
    // method of choice for loading script
    doSomething();
  }
  else {
    // normal logic for doSomething
  }
}
```

Then in your util you would need to modify it so it checks for an existing `window.myUtil` before assigning it. How that would need to look depends on how my utl operates - whether its an object instance or jsut a a literal collection of static functions.

See [this link](http://ntt.cc/2008/02/10/4-ways-to-dynamically-load-external-javascriptwith-source.html) for some methods to actually load the script source.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for `window.myUtil` and if it's undefined, deal with it. That might mean using `setInterval` or `setTimeout` to poll for its existence and when it's found, proceed.

You can also wait for the `load` event, but that might be too late.